# Шахматы(Chess) - Как вывести позиции фигур в случайном порядке?

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм, любой-язык

Господа, надо написать функции:

- Для отрисовки шахматной доски (`function drowChess(8,8)`).
- Для расставления фигур нa ней в произвольном порядке (`function addFigures(['black'=>['King'],'white'=>['Rook','Officer']`). Для начала две противоположные фигуры. Например, король белых и ладья черных, да так, чтобы при каждом вызове этой функции, они не противоречили законам шахмат.
- Функция, по возможности, должна быть универсальной, то есть, если ей передать третью фигуру, она не должна сломаться.

Я думаю так - надо попытаться вычислить алгоритм для их позиции.
Уже начал решать задачу, но что-то с алгоритмом туговато приходится пока что.

```
//Думаю таблица умножения может послужить в качествe доски.
//По-моему, не важно, главное чтоб фигуры по координатам х,y правильно расставились 
    $x = 8;
$y = 8;

$xb = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];

function drowChess($horisonal, $vertical, $xb)
{
    $style = "width:30px;height:30px;";
    $white = "background:white;color:black;text-align:center";
    $black = "background:black;color:white;text-align:center";
    $color = $black;
    echo "<table border='1' style='margin:0 auto' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th style='width:30px;height:30px;'>$horisonal/$vertical</th>";
    foreach($xb as $word){
        echo "<th style='width:30px;height:30px;'>".$word."</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    for($y = 1; $y <= $vertical; $y++)
    {
        if($color == $black)
            $color = $white;
        else
            $color = $black;
        echo "<tr>";
        for($x = 1; $x <= $horisonal; $x++)
        {
            if($color == $black)
                $color = $white;
            else
                $color = $black;
            if($x == 1)
            {
                    echo "<th style='$style'>".$y ."</th>";
            }
            echo "<td style='$style $color'>".$xb[$x-1] .$y."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

drowChess($x, $y,$xb);
```

Думаю начать так:

```
$figures = [
    'King' => function($x,$y)
    {
        //Логика + алгоритм ...
        return [[$x,$y],[$x,$y],[$x,$y]...];//Ну типо возможные позиции , учитывая переданную позицию 
    },
    'Rook' => function($x,$y)
    {
        //Логика + алгоритм ...
        return [[$x,$y],[$x,$y],[$x,$y]...];//учитывая переданную позицию 
    },
    //И так далее для всех фигур
];
```

Как думаетe, как можно это реализовать, или уже есть реализация?
Спасибо.

Comment: а какая связь с явакриптом?

Comment: Думаю что если кто то знает как,то можно код и на javascrip,Неважно,логика она и в Африке логика :)

Comment: тогда лучше поставить метки алгоритм и любой-язык

Comment: Спасибо,поставил :)

Comment: Если речь идет все же о шахматной *игре* (упоминаются же в вопросе "законы шахмат"), то помимо остальных фигур стоит ставить как минимум 2-х королей (белого и черного) (и они не должны бить друг друга). Не знаю, как дальше предполагается использовать создаваемые позиции, но выглядит разумным проверять, что позиция не мат и не пат (иначе, что далее с ней делать?). / Относительно вопроса -- `"...или уже есть реализация?"` -- очевидно, что  в том или ином виде их сотни (или больше).

Comment: Да эта тема про шахматы,но не надо писать всю логико .Тут важно алгоритм написать .Для короля уже написал.Да господа и так все ясно.Давайте больше дела.Кстати на английском задавал вопрос,Там вообще тишина.Пожалуйста напрягите мозги :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче думал я долго и ничего лучше не придумал.А сделал я просто.Взял каждую фигуру и написал логику для каждого его шага.Тут функционал только для короля и ладьи.Думаю кто поймёт то по аналогии может написать и для других фигур.Логика проста,подсчитать их возможные шаги по х,y.

```
drowChess($x, $y,$xb);

$figures = [
    'King' => function ($x,$y)
    {
        if((!$x or $x < 0) or (!$y or $y < 0))
            return "Poziciya $x $y naxoditsya za polem";
        $xb = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];
        $currentPosition = $xb[$x-1].$y;

        $x1 = $x-1;
        $y1 = $y;

        $x2 = $x-1;
        $y2 = $y-1;

        $x3 = $x-1;
        $y3 = $y+1;

        $x4 = $x+1;
        $y4 = $y;

        $x5 = $x+1; 
        $y5 = $y-1;

        $x6 = $x+1; 
        $y6 = $y+1;

        $x7 = $x;   
        $y7 = $y-1;

        $x8 = $x;   
        $y8 = $y+1;

        $positions = [];

        if(isset($xb[$x1-1]) && $y1 && $y1 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x1-1].$y1] = ['x'=>$x1,'y'=>$y1];
        if(isset($xb[$x2-1]) && $y2 && $y2 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x2-1].$y2] = ['x'=>$x2,'y'=>$y2];
        if(isset($xb[$x3-1]) && $y3 && $y3 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x3-1].$y3] = ['x'=>$x3,'y'=>$y3];
        if(isset($xb[$x4-1]) && $y4 && $y4 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x4-1].$y4] = ['x'=>$x4,'y'=>$y4];
        if(isset($xb[$x5-1]) && $y5 && $y5 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x5-1].$y5] = ['x'=>$x5,'y'=>$y5];
        if(isset($xb[$x6-1]) && $y6 && $y6 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x6-1].$y6] = ['x'=>$x6,'y'=>$y6];
        if(isset($xb[$x7-1]) && $y7 && $y7 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x7-1].$y7] = ['x'=>$x7,'y'=>$y7];
        if(isset($xb[$x8-1]) && $y8 && $y8 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x8-1].$y8] = ['x'=>$x8,'y'=>$y8];

        return [
            'Korol na' => $currentPosition,
            'Dostupnie emu xodi'=>$positions
        ];
    },
    'Rook' => function($x,$y)
    {
        if((!$x or $x < 0) or (!$y or $y < 0))
            return "Poziciya $x $y naxoditsya za polem";

        $positions = [];
        $xb = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];
        $currentPosition = $xb[$x-1].$y;

        //V pravo vniz i vverx
        $yrb = $yrt = $y;
        for( $x1 = $x+1; $x1 <= 8 ; $x1++ )
        {
            //Diaganal to rigth bottom
            if((++$yrb) <= 8)
                $positions[$xb[$x1-1].($yrb)] = ['x' => $x1, 'y' => $yrb];

            //Diaganal to rigth top
            if((--$yrt) > 0)
                $positions[$xb[$x1-1].($yrt)] = ['x' => $x1, 'y' => $yrt];
        }

        //V pravo vniz i vverx
        $ylb = $ylt = $y;
        for( $x2 = $x-1; $x2 >= 1 ; $x2-- )
        {
            //Diaganal to left bottom
            if((++$ylb) <= 8){
                $positions[$xb[$x2-1].($ylb)] = ['x' => $x2, 'y' => $ylb];
            }

            //Diaganal to left top
            if((--$ylt) > 0){
                $positions[$xb[$x2-1].($ylt)] = ['x' => $x2, 'y' => $ylt];
            }
        }

        return [
            'Rook na' => $currentPosition,
            'Dostupnie emu xodi'=>$positions
        ];
    },
];
echo "<pre>";
//Доступные шаги для лады
print_r($figures['Rook'](5,5));
//Доступные шаги для Короля
print_r($figures['King'](6,8));
```

Ну а коль имеем доступные шаги то можем написать функцию которая будет вызывать их с разными параметрами до тех пор пока их доступные шаги не будут разными.